# iOSでAppGroupを利用したいのですが、初期設定で共用エリアにデータベースファイルを移動しておく方法を知りたい

Tags: swift, ios8

共用エリアに作っておいたデータベースファイルを、インストール時に移動するか、できなければ、なんらかの方法でコピーする方法がわかりません。

どうしたらいいのか、教えていただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

下記はテストで使っていますが、うまく動きません。

```
var realmPath: String {
    let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGroupKeybora")
    let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory , NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let databaseStr = "Dictionary.realm"
    let dbPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingString("/" + databaseStr)
    var TodbPath = containerURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(databaseStr).path!


    // BEGING MODIFICATION
    let fileMan = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath)) {    // The database does not already exist in Documents directory
        if let source = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingString(databaseStr) {
            if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(source)) {
                print("RealmDB - file \(databaseStr) not found in bundle")

            } else {
                do {
                    try fileMan.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath: TodbPath)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("RealmDB - failed to copy writable version of DB!")
                    print("Error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // END MODIFICATION

    return TodbPath
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あなたのコードはドキュメントディレクトリに`"Dictionary.realm"`というファイルがあるかどうをチェックして、無ければ何もしないという処理になっているので（当然ドキュメントディレクトリにファイルは無いので）、期待した通りに動かないのはそういう理由だと思います。

「共有コンテナ」にファイルがあるかどうかをチェックして、無ければ「バンドル」からファイルを「共有コンテナ」にコピーする、というのが期待している処理だと思いますので、そのように書く必要があります。

ラフに修正したのが下記になります。

```
let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.io.realm.RealmAppCom")
let databaseStr = "Dictionary.realm"
let TodbPath = containerURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(databaseStr).path!

let fileMan = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(TodbPath)) {    // The database does not already exist in Documents directory
    if let source = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(databaseStr, ofType: nil) {
        if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(source)) {
            print("RealmDB - file \(databaseStr) not found in bundle")

        } else {
            do {
                try fileMan.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath: TodbPath)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("RealmDB - failed to copy writable version of DB!")
                print("Error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

return TodbPath
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。この場合、バンドルのDictionary.realmはどこに置くと正しく動作するでしょうか？お忙しいところすみませんが，よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 自己解決しました。ありがとうございました。